# Favorites tab claims there was activity, but doesn't tell me where

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

I really do not understand the "Favorites" tab.  Today it was annotated with a little **2**, which I understand to mean that two of my starred posts have had activity, or perhaps that two events of interest have occurred in my starred posts.  But when I visited the favorites tab, I found that it wouldn't tell me what posts had actually had new activity:

[image: Screenshot of my favorites tab]

Usually there are some beige-highlighted posts at the top of this list, and I can visit them to see what is new.  (Sometimes it appears that nothing *is* new, but that is a separate question.)  This time there were none.  None of the five sub-tabs (“votes”, “activity”, “newest”, “views”, “added”) displayed anything that seemed to be new.

I *think* there is a UI design failure here, but I'm not sure what it is.

Added 2014-01-30: Here's today's update.  Three somethings, but only one highlighted:

[image: Another screenshot]

Added 2014-03-20: Today it highlighted [Earliest precursor to category theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690659/earliest-precursor-to-category-theory) , but that question has not received an edit since 2014-03-02, and no new comment since 2014-02-27.

Comment: It's Heisenberg's Uncertainty principle. It can tell you if there's been activity, or it can tell you where. Not both. (And what's life without mystery?)

Comment: My working hypothesis is that the missing changes are touches by Community that randomly bring old Questions back to the "front page" via pseudo-activity.

Answer (score 1):

The UI elements to which the question refers are on the way out anyway. Due to the recent acquisition of Stack Exchange by LinkedIn<sup>[*]</sup>, the profile pages will be made consistent across both networks. I expect that [when this happens](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226177/251274), the highlighting of favorites will be the least of our worries.

[image: sample]

<sup><sub>[*] okay, not really — it only looks that way.</sub></sup>

Comment: You had me really scared there for a few seconds.